# The method 'call' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, nosuchmethoderror

I am currently working on an app the takes datetime from user and stores it.
I am using a callback that passes datetime from child to parent but keep getting the following error.

In DateTimePicker class, onPressed executes the callBack function where it passes the date to its parent and that is probably where my issue is.

I am new to flutter and I think my code is a bit messy but some help would be highly appreciated.

```
     The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
     The method 'call' was called on null.
     Receiver: null
     Tried calling: call(Instance of 'DateTime')
```

Code from child class(where I think is the issue)

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

    class DateTimePicker extends StatelessWidget {

      final Function callBack;

      const DateTimePicker({Key key, this.callBack}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        String _date = "Not set";
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                elevation: 4.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                      theme: DatePickerTheme(
                        containerHeight: 250.0,
                        cancelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 22, color: Colors.red),
                        doneStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 22, color: Colors.blue),
                        itemStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black),
                        itemHeight: 50,
                      ),
                      showTitleActions: true,
                      minTime: DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
                      maxTime: DateTime(2022, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
                    print('confirm $date');
                    callBack(date);
                    _date = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date);
                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 65,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.calendar_today,
                                  size: 28.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 20,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  " $_date",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  Change",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(79, 67, 67, 1),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Code from Parent class

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import '../widgets/date_picker.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import '../providers/event_provider.dart';

    class EventPicker extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _EventPickerState createState() => _EventPickerState();
    }

    class _EventPickerState extends State<EventPicker> {
      String eventName;

      String dateTime;

      void callBack(DateTime dateFromChild) {
        this.dateTime = dateFromChild.toIso8601String();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final add = Provider.of<EventProviders>(context);

        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 60.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Add Events',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                    ),
                  ),
                  DateTimePicker(),
                  SizedBox(height: 27),
                  Theme(
                    data: ThemeData(
                      primaryColor: Colors.grey,
                      primaryColorDark: Colors.red,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          eventName = value;
                        },
                        autofocus: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Event',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          ),
                          hintText: 'eg: Exam ',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)
                              .copyWith(fontFamily: 'Lato'),
                        ),
                        maxLength: 20,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => add.addEvent(eventName, dateTime),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.save,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: ```DateTimePicker(callback: callBack)```, you forgot to pass the callback parameter. It's also a good practice to null check optional params

Comment: @danypata. Thanks . Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

"NoSuchMethodError method was called on null" errors are usually thrown when the variable where the method was called may have yet to be initialized. In this instance, `DateTimePicker()` expects `Function callBack` but hasn't found any.